# Java store config and other files

Tags: java, exe

Currently i am storing a few config files and a `history.xml` file right next to my executable `.exe`.

However some users have reported that they have to run my program with Administrator rights, otherwise settings and history is not saved to these files.

Where should i save my config files and `history.xml` in order to not require my users to run the app with administrator rights?

Would be really nice with a solution that works on both Windows and OSX

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the C partion need administrator right to run your parogram in Windows 7. Can you try run it in another partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your users are probably saving the files in a folder under Program Files or another 'protected' folder.

Either they should save it in a users-folder, or you should work with a full path to some path on the system, like 'C:/myapp/'.

You can use a helper function to check if you're using Windows or *Nix, and then depending on that return a certain path. I'm not close to my computer so can't test but this should work:

```
return System.getProperty("os.name").egualsIgnoreCase("Windows");
```

You can also make use of "user.home" for the users home directory (always writeable) and "file.separator" so you don't even need to check whether you're on Windows or not.